# Programatically find range of scale fill with geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I made two hex grid plots and I wanted to to give the colour fill the same range so that any given colour means the same thing on both plots. However to set the range I had to manually input what I saw the upper range to be after looking at both plots. I want to be able to just get the max (and min) count in any hex grid between the two (or more) plots programmatically and set that to be the range instead of doing it manually.

I reduced my code to just generate one of the hex grid plots and removed my custom theme. The data comes from the Lahman

```
library(Lahman)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

gg_base_runs <- ggplot(Teams, aes(y = R)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(begin = 0, end = .9, option = "C", limit = range(c(1,150))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1750)) +
  labs(y = "Runs")

(gg_runs_BB_hex <- gg_base_runs + 
  aes(x = BB) + 
  labs(x = "Walks") +
  geom_hex())
```

[image: Current plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation like this, I would normally calculate the count values outside of ggplot in order to find the range of counts. But in this case, it might be easier to use `ggplot_build` to extract the count values directly from each plot object. Once we have the counts for each plot, we can find the range of the counts across *all* the plots. This range can then be used to set the same limits in `scale_fill_viridis` for all the plots. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Lahman)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
```

First we recreate your plot without the call to `scale_fill_viridis`:

```
gg_base_runs <- ggplot(Teams, aes(y = R)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1750)) +
  labs(y = "Runs")

(gg_runs_BB_hex <- gg_base_runs + 
    aes(x = BB) + 
    labs(x = "Walks") +
    geom_hex())
```

Let's also create a second plot so we'll have another plot to work with:

```
set.seed(49)
df = data.frame(x=runif(10000), y=runif(10000))
gg1 = ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_hex(bins=5)
```

Now let's get the range of hexbin counts across both plots

```
count.range = range(lapply(list(gg1, gg_runs_BB_hex), function(p){
  ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$count
}))
```

We can then apply this range to both plots:

```
plot.list = lapply(list(gg1, gg_runs_BB_hex), function(p) {
  p + scale_fill_viridis(begin = 0, end = .9, option = "C", limits = count.range)
})
```

And here's what the plots look like:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=plot.list, ncol=2)
```

[image]